# Flying from Halifax via London to India and back from Jeddah

Tags: air-travel, cancellations

I have a flight booked (round trip) from Halifax, Canada to Jeddah, Saudi Arabia via London. Now there has been a change in my plans and I want to go to India

Can I book a flight from UK to India so that I can use at least a portion of the ticket?

Even if I don't use the ticket from Halifax to Saudi Arabia, can I still use the return ticket to come back to Halifax from Jeddah (since I will be going to Jeddah from India)?

Comment: Contact your airline or the seller of your ticket. If you do not it is very likely that you will not be able to use any of your ticket after you skip using one part. So non of the return journey.

Answer (score 4):

You can fly to the UK on your original ticket, but your remaining flights will be cancelled when you don't show up for the London-Jeddah leg.

Your best bet would likely be to get in touch with the airline/travel agent and see if they can convert your ticket into an **open jaw**: Halifax-India, "surface leg" from India to Jeddah, then back from Jeddah to Halifax. This way all you need to do is buy a one-way from India to Jeddah.

Alternatively, just fly to Jeddah and book a return flight from there to India. This would be straightforward and not necessarily any more expensive once you factor in the change fees; but of course it's a bit of a detour/hassle on the way in.

Answer (score 1):

Airlines *hate* when you do that.  If you do not take both legs of your outward journey, they will cancel the return ticket, re-sell your seat, and not refund your money.

You are probably better off re-writing the ticket with your agent or just to Jeddah as planned then heading straight on to India, which will be about $400.